# Parameter count mismatch in Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parameter-passing

I am getting

> Parameter count mismatch.

exception when I am trying to run the below unit test. I am passing the relevant params and count is correct. Why it is throwing an exception?

```
List<TransactionVM> transactionList = new List<TransactionVM> {
    new TransactionVM {OrderDetailID = 1, QuantityReceived=125, UnitCost=100.00},
    new TransactionVM {OrderDetailID = 1, QuantityReceived=130, UnitCost=200.00},
};

public OrderServiceTest()
{
    Mock<IOrderManager> mockOrderManager = new Mock<IOrderManager>();
    mockOrderManager.Setup(mr => mr.Receive(It.IsAny<List<TransactionVM>>(), It.IsAny<string()))
                    .Returns((TransactionVM target) =>
                             {
                                 target.RoleID = transactionList.Count() + 1;
                                 transactionList.Add(target);
                                 return "OrderReceived";
                             });
    this.MockOrderManager = mockOrderManager.Object;
}

[TestMethod]
public void CanReceiveOrder()
{
    List<TransactionVM> transactionList = new List<TransactionVM> {
        new TransactionVM {OrderDetailID = 1, QuantityReceived=125, UnitCost=100.00}
    };

    this.MockOrderManager.Receive(transactionList, "Permanent");
    int productCount = transactionList.Count();
    Assert.AreEqual(3, transactionList);
}
```

Signature in the interface

```
string Receive(List<TransactionVM> transactionVMList, string priceChangeStatus);
```

I am getting the exception when I am executing `this.MockOrderManager.Receive(transactionList, "Permanent");` line in `CanReceiveOrder()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `.Returns()` method does not implement the correct signature when you are doing the setup (hence the 'mismatch' error).

The `.Returns()` method has to take a lambda function which matches the `Receive()` method signature. Then you have access to the parameters with which the mock object was called, which would usually determine the returned value.

Try this instead:

```
mockOrderManager.Setup(mr => mr.Receive(It.IsAny<List<TransactionVM>>(), It.IsAny<string()))
                .Returns((List<TransactionVM> target, string status) =>
                         {
                             // update logic here...
                             // target.RoleID = transactionList.Count() + 1;
                             // transactionList.Add(target);
                             return "OrderReceived";
                         });
```

The bigger problem is that it looks like you are testing your mock, rather than your business object. Your test class is called `OrderServiceTest`, but you never create an order service.

My advice for creating unit tests is to use the 'should' naming convention and a 'AAA' (Arrange, Act, Assert) layout. Here's an example loosely based on your question:

```
[TestMethod]
public void OrderService_ShouldReceiveOrder()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockOrderManager = new Mock<IOrderManager>();
    mockOrderManager.Setup(It.IsAny<List<TransactionVM>>(), "Permanent")
                    .Returns("OrderReceived");

    var orderService = new OrderService(mockOrderManager.Object);
    orderService.AddOrder(new TransactionVM());

    // Act
    orderService.ProcessOrders();

    // Assert
    mockOrderManager.Verify(_ => _.Receive(It.IsAny<List<TransactionVM>>(),
                                           "Permanent"));
}
```

I think this makes it very clear what you are testing, and what you expect your test to do.